# MySQL query to fetch data from product table and all the related photos from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query that I used to fetch all the products from the main table and with a join it also fetch the related photos from another table. The problem, with this query, is that it duplicates the result when I print it on screen (as far as I understood it does because there are two photos per products).

I would like to print every products only once but with all the two photos. Searching the web I understood that I need somehow to group the data but honestly I am not so good. How should I modify this query to achieve this goal?

```
"SELECT tbl_prodotti.id AS id,
        tbl_prodotti.nome AS nome,
        tbl_prodotti.kg AS kg,
        tbl_prodotti.tipologia_prodotto AS tipologia_prodotto,
        tbl_prodotti.s_pc AS s_pc,
        tbl_prodotti.potere_calorico AS potere_calorico,
        tbl_prodotti.s_ceneri AS s_ceneri,
        tbl_prodotti.ceneri AS ceneri,
        tbl_prodotti.certificazione AS certificazione,
        tbl_prodotti.rif_certificazione AS rif_certificazione,
        tbl_prodotti.essenze AS essenze,
        tbl_prodotti.s_diametro AS s_diametro,
        tbl_prodotti.diametro AS diametro,
        tbl_prodotti.diametro2 AS diametro2,
        tbl_prodotti.s_lung AS s_lung,
        tbl_prodotti.lunghezza AS lunghezza,
        tbl_prodotti.s_larghezza AS s_larghezza,
        tbl_prodotti.larghezza AS larghezza,
        tbl_prodotti.s_umidita AS s_umidita,
        tbl_prodotti.umidita AS umidita,
        tbl_prodotti.s_durabilita AS s_durabilita,
        tbl_prodotti.durabilita AS durabilita,
        tbl_prodotti.s_pf AS s_pf,
        tbl_prodotti.polveri_fini AS polveri_fini,
        tbl_prodotti.s_add AS s_add,
        tbl_prodotti.additivi AS additivi,
        tbl_prodotti.disponibilita AS disponibilita,
        tbl_imgs.foto AS foto,
        tbl_imgs.posizione AS posizione,
        tbl_certificazione.nome AS riferimento_certificazione
        FROM tbl_prodotti
        LEFT JOIN tbl_imgs
        ON tbl_imgs.id_prodotto = tbl_prodotti.id
        LEFT JOIN tbl_certificazione
        ON tbl_certificazione.id = tbl_prodotti.rif_certificazione
        WHERE tbl_prodotti.tipologia_prodotto = :tipologia_prodotto
        ORDER BY tbl_prodotti.id ASC"
```

Edit: Below the query updated and part of my php code to explode the result and cycle through it.

```
SELECT tbl_prodotti.id AS id,
       tbl_prodotti.nome AS nome,
       tbl_prodotti.kg AS kg,
       tbl_prodotti.tipologia_prodotto AS tipologia_prodotto,
       tbl_prodotti.s_pc AS s_pc,
       tbl_prodotti.potere_calorico AS potere_calorico,
       tbl_prodotti.s_ceneri AS s_ceneri,
       tbl_prodotti.ceneri AS ceneri,
       tbl_prodotti.certificazione AS certificazione,
       tbl_prodotti.rif_certificazione AS rif_certificazione,
       tbl_prodotti.essenze AS essenze,
       tbl_prodotti.s_diametro AS s_diametro,
       tbl_prodotti.diametro AS diametro,
       tbl_prodotti.diametro2 AS diametro2,
       tbl_prodotti.s_lung AS s_lung,
       tbl_prodotti.lunghezza AS lunghezza,
       tbl_prodotti.s_larghezza AS s_larghezza,
       tbl_prodotti.larghezza AS larghezza,
       tbl_prodotti.s_umidita AS s_umidita,
       tbl_prodotti.umidita AS umidita,
       tbl_prodotti.s_durabilita AS s_durabilita,
       tbl_prodotti.durabilita AS durabilita,
       tbl_prodotti.s_pf AS s_pf,
       tbl_prodotti.polveri_fini AS polveri_fini,
       tbl_prodotti.s_add AS s_add,
       tbl_prodotti.additivi AS additivi,
       tbl_prodotti.disponibilita AS disponibilita,                        
       tbl_imgs.posizione AS posizione,
       tbl_certificazione.nome AS riferimento_certificazione,
       group_concat(tbl_imgs.foto ORDER BY posizione) as immagini
       FROM tbl_prodotti
       LEFT JOIN tbl_imgs
       ON tbl_imgs.id_prodotto = tbl_prodotti.id
       LEFT JOIN tbl_certificazione
       ON tbl_certificazione.id = tbl_prodotti.rif_certificazione
       WHERE tbl_prodotti.tipologia_prodotto = :tipologia_prodotto
       AND disponibilita <> :disponibilita
       GROUP BY tbl_prodotti.id
       ORDER BY tbl_prodotti.id ASC"
```

Here, part of my php code to explode the result and cycle through it:

```
$i = 0;
$totale = '';
$immagini = array();
$immagini = explode(',', $row['immagini']);
$totale = count($immagini);
while($i < $totale){
$html .= "<img src='" . $immagini[$i] . "' class='img-thumbnail p-img mt-4 ms-2 me-2' alt='giorgio pellet sanremo'>";
$i++;
}
```

Comment: A JOIN that has not a 1:1 relationship will multiply the rows, you need to loop over every and detect every duplicate row, and extract onbly the image a little flow control an evry thing will loo good. Your problem is in the php code not the mysql query

Comment: ok thanks and in my case, as the problem is in the photos (foto), in the foreach loop how can i check this? I have the code like this:

foreach($rows as $row) {
   ...
  $row['foto'];
}

Can you point me to some example please?

Comment: please shoew your php code as well, also helpfull a result set to see  the duplicate rows, that you mentioned

Comment: Use `GROUP_CONCAT(tbl_imgs.foto)` to turn it into a comma-separated list. Then you can explode it in PHP.

Comment: Thanks Barmar and sorry for the late reply. Your hint remind me that I had same problem long time ago. So i did a deep search in my old projects and i discovered the solution and it was like you said. I used group_concat in my query and then exploded the result et voila!. Now i edit my question with the updated query and part of the code where i explode the result.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in the answer that was edited. For the solution thanks to @Barmar who point me to the right direction